# Recommend way and maximum byte size for requests in a data-intensive Django application

Tags: django, postgresql, csv, django-rest-framework, filesize

I am working on an application that handles datasets with varyiing sizes.
For POST requests I do a check on the attached .csv-File for byte size like and if its over 10mb, I return a BAD_REQUEST response:

```
MAX_FILESIZE_BYTES = 10485760 # 10mb

csvFile = request.data["file"]
if(csvFile.size > MAX_FILESIZE_BYTES):
    raise Exception("File size over "+str(MAX_FILESIZE_BYTES))

except Exception as e:
    return Response("Uploaded File bigger than maximum filesize", status=BAD_REQUEST, exception=True)
```

Is this the recommend way of handling files too big? And is 10mb a reasonable size, or could my application handle much bigger sizes?
I use rest_framework, atomic transactions with postgresql and I dont expect to have more much than 50 users at the same time.

Comment: 10 megabytes is relatively tiny these days, unless you've deployed your app to run on a toaster. Why do you (think you) need a limit for the upload size?

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea to limit the file size to avoid slow down of the system. I use quite heavy operations and processing and datasets too big would quickly result in long answering times.

Comment: Well, what happens when your user actually does need to upload a 10.1 megabyte file?

Comment: the user shouldnt do that and in my case probably wont. Anyways, we are talking about about application requirements. 
My question was more of a technical nature... What size is generally feasible for data-intensive Django applications? You said 10mb is relatively, small. Even if I have heavy data processing operations?

Comment: What _are_ your "heavy data processing operations"? Remember that a short video taken with a phone camera can be 500 megabytes these days, and those can be processed just fine.

Comment: The data is processed for predictions/forecasts, normalization and more. I implemented everything in pandas.

Comment: btw valohai looks like a super cool project.

Comment: Well, if those operations start taking too much time, you can offload them outside the request/response cycle with worker solutions like huey/django-rq/celery/...; if they start taking too much memory, you can optimize them or run your app on a bigger machine.

Comment: I read about celery and I will consider that. As I have kept performance in mind at all time and tried to use principles like the vectorized operations in pandas as often as possible, I dont think it will be neccessary any time soon. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the recommend way of handling files too big?

Well, it seems a bit weird that you'd raise an exception just to catch it.

```
MAX_FILESIZE_BYTES = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # 10 MiB

if request.data["file"].size > MAX_FILESIZE_BYTES:
    return Response(
        "Uploaded file bigger than maximum filesize", 
        status=BAD_REQUEST,
        exception=True,
    )
```

is simpler.

> And is 10mb a reasonable size, or could my application handle much bigger sizes?

As I said in my comment, 10 mb is relatively tiny these days, so unless you're running on a very small machine, or your "quite heavy operations" are very heavy indeed, it's a pretty low limit.

Also, consider the case where your user actually needs to upload a file that's, say, 10.1 megabytes in size – they'll just complain that your app doesn't allow them to do that.

> Simply stated: You will either need zero of a thing, one of a thing, or an arbitrary number of the thing.
> Programmers and architects ignore this at their own peril. **Arbitrary fixed limits are a Code Smell.**

– [Zero-One-Infinity Rule](https://wiki.c2.com/?ZeroOneInfinityRule)

Sure, if your app allows just *anyone* to start uploading a gigabyte of data, you might want to set a very high arbitrary "safety" limit, but if it's e.g. an internal tool of some sort, I'd just get rid of the limit altogether. If your user tries to upload a large enough file, the "quite heavy" operation will likely fail, and they'll complain about *that*, not that your app doesn't let them do their work.